# OpenCart 3 header image from module

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I would like to add an Image as background by selecting from a module. The new extension is created under starter_module name.

Please, do not suggest to add image in css file.

The image set in module is not saving, this would be the issue, if you know the solution, please add in your comment.

Many thanks,

I added in: admin/view/template/extension/module/starter_module.twig

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-headbg">Header Image</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <a href="" id="thumb-headbg" data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="{{ headbg }}" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" />
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" name="config_headbg" value="{{ config_headbg }}" id="input-headbg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In admin/controller/extension/module/starter_module.php

```
//Top page
// Module Image
$this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('config_headbg', $this->request->post);
// Module Image
// Module Image

if (isset($this->request->post['config_headbg'])) {
    $data['headbg'] = $this->request->post['config_headbg'];
} else {
    $data['headbg'] = $this->config->get('config_headbg');
}
$this->load->model('tool/image');

if (isset($this->request->post['config_headbg']) && is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->request->post['config_headbg'])) {
    $data['headbg'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->request->post['config_headbg'], 100, 100);
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_headbg') && is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_headbg'))) {
    $data['headbg'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->config->get('config_headbg'), 100, 100);
} else {
    $data['headbg'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 100, 100);
}
$data['placeholder'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 100, 100);

// Module Image
```

In catalog/controller/common/header.php

```
if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_headbg'))) {
    $data['headbg'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_headbg');
} else {
    $data['headbg'] = '';
}
```

In catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.twig

```
{{ headbg }}
```

Many thanks,

The files you check here https://github.com/bblori/OpenCart3-Module-Header-Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to opencart but from what I see in your form the input is named headbg
`<input type="hidden" name="headbg" value="{{ config_headbg }}" id="input-headbg" />` and in admin controller you check for config_headbg `if (isset($this->request->post['config_headbg']))`

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code, I tried by adding this  in admin/controller/setting/setting.php, admin/view/template/setting.twig and in that way is working all codes. Now I need to figure it out what else need to be added in extension files to get working from there.